# Sveltestrap Dropdown selected value

Tags: svelte, svelte-3

I am trying to use sveltestrap dropdown.  How should I get the selected value ?

I tried on:change function but its not working

```
<script lang="ts">
  import {
    Dropdown,
    DropdownItem,
    DropdownMenu,
    DropdownToggle,
  } from "sveltestrap";

  let selected = "1";

  let call = () => {
    console.log("function called");
  };
</script>

<Dropdown>
  <DropdownToggle caret 
    >Select Device Type</DropdownToggle
  >
  <DropdownMenu bind:value={selected} on:change="{call}">
    <DropdownItem value="1">A</DropdownItem>
    <DropdownItem value="2">B</DropdownItem>
    <DropdownItem value="3">C</DropdownItem>
  </DropdownMenu>
</Dropdown>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it offers such feature out of box, but it's easy to implement:

```
<Dropdown>
  <DropdownToggle caret
    >Select Device Type</DropdownToggle
  >
  <DropdownMenu>
    {#each ['1', '2', '3'] as value}
      <DropdownItem
        active={value === selected}
        on:click={() => selected=value}
      >
        {value}
      </DropdownItem>
    {/each}
  </DropdownMenu>
</Dropdown>
```